# Forgot to pick up my Biometric Residence Permit; what can I do?

Tags: united-kingdom, residence-cards

I forgot to pick up my BRP card when I was in London. What should I do and how can I get it so I can work?

Comment: Are you outside the UK now?

Answer (score 6):

Do you have your decision letter? It should have told you which post office your BRP was to be collected from, or if you were to collect it from your sponsor.

Your options if you were supposed to collect it in London and you're not currently in London would be ([source](https://www.gov.uk/biometric-residence-permits/collect)):

1. Travel back to the original collection location, pick it up.
2. Find a [local Post Office branch](http://www.postoffice.co.uk/branch-finder) that offers "BRP collection service", arrange to have it sent there instead (involves a fee).

You're only supposed to nominate someone to collect for you if you have a disability or illness that prevents you going yourself.

If you aren't sure where you were supposed to pick up your BRP, you can report a collection problem: https://www.biometric-residence-permit.service.gov.uk/collection/where

Comment: My letter did have post office one it but it just slipped my mind when I got to London full of excitement to look around and now I've been travelling and going to Belfast to find work and got asked for it at the Irish boarder. I'm going to the Aus embassy straight away to explained and see if they can help.